# When opening a new link on my site on desktop, it loads the mobile css instead on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

When I am on my site and I use the middle mouse button to load the page in a new tab, it renders the page as if it was on mobile but it is actually on desktop. It only recently started doing this on Chrome after an update.

As the site was done before I joined they did not use media query's like they should have, but actually used a mobile CSS file and a desktop CSS file. Depending on the size of the screen it loads the one it needs.

What I think is happening is that when the page loads in a new tab it loads it in a smaller screen, making my script believe it is on mobile but actually it is on Desktop.

jQuery:

```
function ResolutionSwitcher(config) {
        this.cutoff = document.cutoff || 980;
        this.$head = $(document.querySelector("head"));
        $.extend(this, config);
    }

    ResolutionSwitcher.prototype.appendStyle = function(url) {
        this.$head.append($("<link/>", {
            type: "text/css",
            rel: "stylesheet",
            href: url
        }));
    };

    ResolutionSwitcher.prototype.removeStyle = function(url) {
        this.$head.find("link[href$='" + url + "']").remove();
    };

    ResolutionSwitcher.prototype.onDesktop = function() {
        this.appendStyle("/static/public/css/desktop.v2.css");
        this.removeStyle("mobile.css");
        DesktopLayout.init();
    };

    ResolutionSwitcher.prototype.onMobile = function() {
        this.appendStyle("/static/public/css/mobile.v2.css");
        this.removeStyle("desktop.v2.css");
        MobileLayout.init();
    };

    ResolutionSwitcher.prototype.checkResolution = function() {
        var desktop_cutoff = 460;

        // if screen is smaller than cutoff (mobile)
        if(this.cutoff >= screen.width) {
                this.onMobile();
                window.site_version = 'strict_mobile';
            }

        // if screen is bigger than cutoff but window is smaller than cutoff and version is not already mobile
        else if(desktop_cutoff >= window.outerWidth && window.site_version != 'mobile') {
                this.onMobile();
                window.site_version = 'mobile';
                // navScrolling('#secondList');
                // navScrolling('#thirdList');
                navScrolling();
            }

        // if screen and window are both wider than cutoff and version is not already desktop
        else if(desktop_cutoff < window.outerWidth && window.site_version != 'desktop') {
                this.onDesktop();
                window.site_version = 'desktop';
                // navScrolling('#secondList');
                // navScrolling('#thirdList');
                navScrolling();
            }
    };
return ResolutionSwitcher;
```

Comment: Your JS is being cached. TO prevent caching, add a random int <script src="test.js?version=1"></script> to your script tag. So put it in a external file.

Comment: @Raymond I have just done that, and it worked, but it is causing a few styling issues. Or could this be an completely another issue?

Comment: Another issue probably, unless relative paths are in the JS file, which they are. So update the location of the file's paths.